# How to execute a file without .sh extension in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I want to execute a file in bash without the .sh extension.

Example: I have file "abc.sh" which I can execute directly (as I have added #!/bin/bash as the first line) but I want the filename to be just "abc"

Comment: Just `chmod +x abc`. The extension is meaningless in linux

Comment: When it is not in your PATH (variable telling where to look for execuatble programs), you should start like `./abc` (as @WasteD mentions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Linux you use `./filename` too run a script. And you need execute permission:

`chmod 755 filename`

But you still need the "Shebang":

```
#!/bin/bash
```

From [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html) I got this:

> If you did not put the scripts directory in your PATH, and . (the
> current directory) is not in the PATH either, you can activate the
> script like this:
>
> **./script_name.sh**
>
> A script can also explicitly be executed by a given shell, but
> generally we only do this if we want to obtain special behavior, such
> as checking if the script works with another shell or printing traces
> for debugging:
>
> **rbash** script_name.sh
>
> **sh** script_name.sh
>
> **bash** -x script_name.sh

Comment: This has solved a problem for me but why does ./filename work? I can't find anything on google to explain it.

and how would you execute a script from a directory without changing directory say for example you're in the home directory and from there you want to execute a script called filename located in /some/nested/directory how would that be done?

Comment: @QuestionMcquestioner I edited my answer. Hopefully you understand now!

Comment: Yeah, it makes a little bit more sense now; thank you very much

Comment: Shebang is not really needed when the script can be run in the current shell. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for details.

Answer (score 17):

If the file is already executable as `abc.sh`, then all you need to do is rename the file:

```
mv abc.sh abc
```

(assuming you are in the directory where the file lives)

In a Linux or Unix shell, the file extension doesn't affect whether it will execute or not.

Answer (score 2):

What are the permissions on the file? To make it executable with doing something like `./abc.sh` it needs to have EXECUTABLE rights.

You can always do `bash abc.sh`

[Linux permissions overview](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm)

Filename in Linux doesn't mean anything in terms of execution capabilities, you can call the file `myfile.something.something` and it can still be executable. You can name it `abc` but it has to have `EXECUTABLE` rights for the user,group,other.

To add that permission you can do `chmod +x <filename>` but you should look at the link above for a better understanding.

Comment: it has 755 permissions but Can I use it as just abc?

Comment: Who owns the file, who is trying to use the file? All of these things matter in execution while filename doesn't.

Comment: If you want to run it as `abc`, you have several options, for instance: (1) Just name it `abc` instead of `abc.sh`, (2) Create a symbolic link from `abc` to `abc.sh`, (3) Provide an alias named `abc` refering to `abc.sh` (4) Create a shell script `abc`, which runs `abc.sh`,.....